# Brightcove video keeps playing in background even after modal dialog gets closed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, brightcove

I have implemented following implementation to open Brightcove video in modal dialog on button click.

Here is the code for my implemenation.

**Html code:**

```html
<a class="videoTutorialB" href="#">Watch video tutorial</a>
<div id="watchvideopopup" class="modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div id="closevideopopup" aria-label="Close" role="button">Close</div>
    <div id="watch-video-tutorial"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript code.**

```js
var playerInstance;
    
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".videoTutorialB").click(function() {
    $("#watchvideopopup").css("background","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)");
    init();
    $("#watchvideopopup").addClass('temp');
  });
    
  $("#closevideopopup").click(function() {
    terminate();
    $("#watchvideopopup").css("background","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
    $("#watchvideopopup").removeClass('temp');
    $("#watchvideopopup").css("display","none");
  });
});
    
function init() {
  var container = document.getElementById('watch-video-tutorial');
  var playerHTML;
  var data = {
    videoId: '4845831078001',
    accountId: '1752604059001',
    playerId: 'default'
  };
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "https://players.brightcove.net/" + data.accountId + "/" + data.playerId + "_default/index.min.js";
  script.id = "brightcoveJs";

  playerHTML = '<video-js id=\"brightcovePlayer\" ' +
    ' data-video-id=\"' + data.videoId + '\" ' +
    ' data-account=\"' + data.accountId + '\" ' +
    ' data-player=\"' + data.playerId + '\" ' +
    ' data-embed=\"default\" class=\"video-js\" ' +
    ' controls></video-js>';

  container.innerHTML = playerHTML;
  container.appendChild(script);

  script.onload = callback;
}

function callback() {
  playerInstance = bc('brightcovePlayer');
  playerInstance.on('loadedmetadata', function () {
    playerInstance.play();
  })
}

function play() {
  playerInstance.play();
}

function pause() {
  playerInstance.;
}

function terminate() {
  document.getElementById('brightcovePlayer').remove();
  document.getElementById('brightcoveJs').remove();

  delete playerInstance;
}
```

The Brightcove video is not playing in background when I close the modal dialog after video gets fully loaded or while playing and video successfully removed from DOM.

**But if close the modal dialog before the Brightcove video get loaded fully, the Brightcove video starts playing in background even after I closed the modal dialog.**

**My requirement is Brightcove video should not play in the background even though I close the
modal dialog before Brightcove video before fully loaded.**

Answer (score 0):

Use `playerInstance.dispose()` instead of `document.getElementById('brightcovePlayer').remove();`. That removes the player instance and not just its element from the DOM.